# related network error using roles in mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I m using Identity.2 to manage roles in my asp mvc 5 website.
Everything works fine in for me. But my colleague get a

> network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing
>   a connection to SQL Server

in this line :

`User.IsInRole("Admin")`

Note that I have an sql express installed in my local poste, this is not the case for my colleague.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is very likely a CONNECTION STRING issue.  Have you revised the connection string to meet the requirements for the configuration your colleague is using?

Comment: Yea the connection string it s good.

Comment: Your colleague doesn't have sql installed? This is what your last line tells.

Comment: He hasn t sql experess in his pc.

Comment: When I stoped the sql express service in my poste I get the same error

Comment: What's server name in your connection string? Is it connecting to your local SQL Server instance?

Comment: The server name is Server-DB-DEV, it' s a remote server